# Get integer prediction for regressor models with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, forecasting

I'm using sklearn regressor models to forecast sales by day. However, I want the output to be an integer (because I cannot sell half product) so I'm trying to get the prediction output as an integer, but I cannot find the way.

I know I can transform the float to int, but my question is about the posibility to adjust the model to generate integer prediction (as the inputs are integer numbers too).

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import BayesianRidge

model_trained = model.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_est = model_trained.predict(x_test)

print(x_test) --> [645 198 546 619 748]

print(y_est) --> [486.84247399 352.79511474 545.31309247 499.17395514 723.32887889]
```

Comment: Hacks aside (like the one described in the answer below), there is no such possibility; the math and stats of regression apply only to real numbers (floats). You should just do the rounding at the end as a postprocessing stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value for the `predict` methods is of the type `float`. You would have to override the regressor models to change the implementation of the `predict` methods.

Line 215 has the implementation of the method for the `KNeighborsRegressor`:

[sklearn KNeighborsRegressor implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/neighbors/_regression.py)

You could try and change the `dtype` parameter on line 240 to `np.intc`, instead of `np.float64`. Here is a list of the acceptable data types:

[numpy data types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html)

I think that it would be easier to transform the list of `floats` into a list of `ints`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [PoissonRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor.html) with log-link, it is for [non-negative integer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#generalized-linear-models) values as in your case (sales cannot be negative)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33814785)